# How to use the ssh-agent in different sessions?

Tags: linux, ssh

I don't really know much about how ssh work, so my question might appear trivial.

I am on linux. I am using ssh to push and pull to my github repository. At the moment, every time I want to push, I need to do the following:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssd-add path/to/key
```

If I close the terminal and open a new one, I need to do the same thing. This seems a bit repetitive. To make matters worse, `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` keeps creating new `ssh-agent` processes. Surely, I must be doing something wrong?

Basically, my question is: why can't the `ssh-agent` lunch automatically and load the keys every time I open a new terminal?

Comment: "why can't the ssh-agent lunch automatically and load the keys every time I open a new terminal?" - Because you're not telling your shell to do that. Which one are you using?